# Localization do not work when "l18parent" is empty (0)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

When a content element is translated using "translate" method and so have a l18parent, the content shows up in frontend.
When using "copy" method or created the content in new language without l18parent the content do not appear in frontend.

Can simply test it when unselecting a l18parent in CE form and selecting a parent again.
See screenshots attached.

With parent, working.
Without parent, not working (not appearing in frontend).

---

Not working

[image: not working]

Working

[image: working]

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 6.2 there is a new setting for the CONTENT object: includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation

see here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Functions/Select/

Before this, the CONTENT object fetched all elements.
After this change, only elements which were correctly translated in the backend with the translation buttons, are displayed, because they have a parent.

Maybe you can check with these settings in your typoscript (at the beginning of your typoscript):

```
styles.content.get.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
styles.content.getLeft.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
styles.content.getRight.select.includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
```

Then all elements should show up again; even the ones without parent.

Original resource for this is written in german here:
http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2014/08/typo3-content-anzeige-von-uebersetzungen-ohne-parent-bzw-default-translation.html

Comment: What the heck? Why did I never heard of it...Thank you!